# Do I need to reach air breakdown voltage to have a macroscopic electron flow between electrodes?

Tags: electric-current, voltage

Do I need to reach air breakdown voltage to have a macroscopic electron flow between electrodes? I'm looking for something like a miliampere (greater than leak current in batteries)

Comment: With pointed electrodes or thin wires one can get some current from corona discharge.

Answer (score 1):

in the case of two electrodes separated by an air gap at ambient pressure, there are several different conduction mechanisms which could be active, depending on (for example) whether or not the electrodes are illuminated by light (and what the wavelength of the light is), whether they are both sharp points or flat surfaces, how far apart they are, and exactly how much voltage exists across them. Generally speaking, you can have what is called "dark discharge" at fairly low voltage (less than ~1000VDC) if the points are sharp, and this could be on the order of hundreds of microamps. this is also referred to as "field emission". Books have been written on the subject of electrical breakdown and conduction of gases, containing far more information than can easily be accommodated in this particular forum.